# Javascript scope of variables not working properly

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I am an amateur programmer having a hard time with a little project.  I would like to get a data from a Google spreadsheet, modify the data, and make a Google Chart (using google chart api).

The below code works perfectly in Firefox but Chrome and IE don't allow the dataTable outside the scope of the handleQueryResponse(e) function. My first thought was to return the dataTable from the handleQueryResponse(e) function but that is called inside of a function (.send()).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getDataTable(link) {
     var dataTable= new google.visualization.DataTable();
     var queryTrip = new google.visualization.Query(link);
     queryTrip.send(handleQueryResponse);
     function handleQueryResponse(response) {

         if (response.isError()) {

             alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
             return;
         }

         dataTable = response.getDataTable();
         // I can verify this has the data through debugging in Chrome  
     }
     // Outside of the function handleQueryResponse the dataTable is gone
    return dataTable;
 }
```

Comment: I assume `queryTrip.send` is asynchronous. In that case you would return `dataTable` from your function before it was set by the callback. That is `return dataTable;` is executed before `dataTable = response.getDataTable();`. You cannot return a value from a function if asynchronous function calls are involved. You should make `getDataTable` accept a callback which you call ones the result is ready and pass it to the callback.

Comment: "allow" makes no sense in this context. All browsers allow to define variables everywhere. Please be more specific: Do you get an error somewhere? If so, tell us the whole error message!

Comment: @JoshMein it's _perfectly_ normal to declare functions inside other functions in Javascript.

Comment: @JoshMein — Is there a reason that function needs to be available in a wider scope?

Comment: I have just never seen it done before and it sort of confused me as of why you would want to. But thanks to your comments, I think I understand a little futher now.

Comment: I wasn't considering the function .send is asynchronous. You are right it is asynchronous. I would like to draw a few graphs with the same dataTable, except I need to modify the data a little bit for each graph.  In a perfect world, I would like dataTable to transcend (better word than allow) the function handleQueryResponse. It does in FireFox but does not in Chrome or IE.

Answer (score 3):

Functions that call asynchronous functions (`queryTrip.send`) **cannot** return data which depends on the result of that asynchronous function call, nor otherwise use the data.

That data is *only* available inside the callback function, and any other function subsequently called *by* that callback.

Answer (score 0):

as felix mentioned, it's probably asynchronous, meaning that variable no longer exists by the time the handleQueryResponse gets run because it's not run instantly within the scope of the function getDataTable.

You could put the variable for dataTable outside that scope ( into global scope ) than the handleQueryResponse would be able to write to it.

However you will want to initiate any functions that need to run after the dataTable is ready from within the handleQueryResponse function. Best course of action might be to use some sort of event driven handling for after the dataTable is ready.

Comment: The problem is not *where* `dataTable` is defined. The problem is *when* it is read and set... in this case it is read (returned) before it was set.